# Filter a table from a Dropdown in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a table in my app and I want to be able to filter the data in the table via a group of different select drop downs? Any ideas / recommended ways of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: please add relevant code, so that we can understand your problem

Comment: Please consider , posting some codes on what have you tried already. And what is the end goal of your issue.